# I remember a pre-2000 Japanese tabletop RPG about a world covered in dungeons (split between air, land, and sea types) – which RPG was it?

Tags: product-identification, dungeon

I remember reading about a pre-2000 Japanese tabletop RPG with black-and-white illustrations, that's about dungeon-building, or being really focused on dungeons.

I think it has a nice tutorial section inside for how to play a person's first RPG, but what really stuck out was that its world was covered in dungeons, that were split between the land, air, and sea, with the oceanic zone just being called the The Depths/The Deeps.

Comment: huh... it's not MAID or Mekton... Anima isn't Japanese but Spanish... with "interior", do you mean untranslated?

Comment: @Trish - I mean that the illustrations on the inside of the book are black and white... Lemme fix this...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### This matches what I know of *Meikyuu Kingdom*

Well, mostly. A lot of *Meikyuu Kingdom* is black and white but the introductory "what is RPG and how do I" bit is a color manga.

Still, though. The conceit of it is that due to some type of magical apocalypse (the "Dungeon Hazard") the entire world has turned into dungeons, split between the Firmament, the Deeps, and Grand Zero in the middle.

The PCs play the role of the nobility and problem-solvers of a tiny point of light, a kingdom you all make together, and venture into the "Million Dungeons" of the wider world to keep their kingdom safe.